# How can I use a defined Array variable from another method?

Tags: java

I want to use an Array variable, which is defined in one method, in another method of the same class.

I tried to directly use it but there is an error saying "cannot find variable". I tried to define the Array variable as static in the front but there is an error saying "Array constant can only be used in initializers".

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test{
    public static void name(){
        String[] list={"a","b"};
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        name();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

And what I want is just the array named `list`.

Comment: You need to read more about variable scopes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made list as a static variable and initialized array using initializer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    static String[] list;

    public static void name(){

       list= new String[]{"a","b"};
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
         name();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Return the value of `list` from the method `name`. That's it change the method signature from return type `void` to `String[]`.

```
public class test {
    public static String[] name(){
        String[] list = {"a","b"};
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name()));
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you could create it as a variable inside `test` class, and then in `main` instantiate that class and call that member variable.

```
public class test {
    // not very safe! using public access modifier
    public String[] list = {"a","b"};
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        test instance = new test();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(instance.list));
    }
}
```

[See demo](https://ideone.com/DOASa0)

Comment: Thanks man. BTW, is this the only way to fix this? if not returing what can I do

Comment: You could create it as a variable inside test class, and then in `main` instantiate that class and call that member variable. Would you prefer better that option?